Two separate Time Machine backups on single HFS+ drive?
I have been keeping Time Machine backups for two separate MacBooks on a single external hard drive by having two APFS volumes on the single APFS-formatted drive. No problems there. Both MacBooks ask for the passwords for both volumes; I just put in the password for whichever computer I'm backing up at that moment.
Now I would like to attach this hard drive to my router in order to do these backups over the local network. But my router will only accept HFS+ drives.
Is it possible to write multiple Time Machine backup usable volumes (is APFS necessary?) to an HFS+ formatted drive?
Before I try and end up screwing something up, I'd like to get some feedback if this has worked for anyone else.

It's a network volume.  Time Machine will back up to a sparsebundle.  Assuming your router isn't doing something odd, the actual filesystem ought to be irrelevant.

I would never trust a router and attached drive for TM backup. Too many things can go wrong even if the vendor says the router supports TM - do they explicitly support TM with your version of macOS? I would definitely use a different hard disk and keep the existing drive in case of issues. YMMV

Also, having a single external device to use TimeMachine for two Macs is a dangerous proposition. If the device becomes a brick, you’ve lost backups to both Macs at once. It’s is a better practice to use a single drive for each Mac, or, in your case, if you want to maintain the setup you are using, two separate Time Machine drives.

Your setup seems ideal to me with one exception. Get a second drive so you cann swap them weekly or monthly. Backing up over the network is a scenario full of pain and you need a processor to share it out and handle the competing writes. What’s your end goal? Getting more hourly intervals? Not connecting a drive? Slowing down the time it makes to backup one Mac?

Just some extra info: these are roving laptops so even at the moment I only backup manually and only once a month or so. Most of my key stuff is cloud based anyway so I'm not horribly worried if I have to revert to a month old TM backup. My plan is to just continue this monthly, manual TM backup, just via the networked drive (which I would only even mount for those backup instances). In theory I think that would mitigate some of the issues you guys have helpfully raised.
